# Laravel - Eloquent: get posts from user with users post table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relation

I searched a lot but could not find any answer about it, so I hope you could help me!

I have three tables: `posts`, `users` and `post_users`.
`Post_users` contains two columns: `user_id` and `post_id`.

I need to get all posts by an user with Eloquent. Any ideas?

Comment: do you already have relationship built?

Comment: Setup relationships like `belongsTo` and `hasMany` and you'll find it a breeze

Comment: No, I didn't. Which relationships and which model should I set? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Model `User`:

```
public function posts()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'post_users', 'user_id', 'post_id');
}
```

Model `Post`:

```
public function users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'post_users', 'post_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Try:

```
$user = User::find($id);
$allpost = $user->posts()->get();
var_dump($allpost);
```

Comment: You're welcome. This's many to many relationship but in your problem you should use one to many relationship.

Answer (score 3):

The Laravel docs cover this pretty well but I had an issue with it when I first started as well. Check out [Laravel Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships) for the fully write up.

```
// Inside your Post model
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

// Inside your User model
public function posts() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Posts');
}
```

You can then create a query:

```
$posts = User::find(1)->posts;
```

Or you can filter it further..

```
$posts = User::find(1)->posts()->where('active', 1)->get();
```

You may need to change your paths for the `hasMany()` and `belongsTo()` if your model location and names are different.

Answer (score 2):

**As you wish. Relation between User and Post is many-to-many**

**- Defined relation**

```
// In User model
public function posts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class);
}
// In Post model
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

**- Table structure**

```
- users
    id
- posts
    id
- post_user
    user_id
    post_id
```

**- Get all post by a user**

```
$posts = User::find($user_id)->posts
```

Comment: I created post_users because many users can edit the post. So, an user can have many posts and a post can have many users

Comment: Edited. Take care of name convention

Answer (score 1):

If you donot have relationship built, try this. However building relationships is preferred. PostUsers and Posts are assumed models of post-users and posts tables, and post as column of the posts table. this gives the posts of logged in user, but not tested.

```
$postusers=PostUsers::where(['user_id'=>Auth::user()->id])->get();
foreach($postusers as $postuser)
{
        $posts=Posts::where(['post_id'=>$postuser->post_id)]->get();
        foreach($posts as $post)
         {
            print_r($post->post);
         }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm looking for relationships way

Answer (score 1):

Try this

From Controller :

```
dd(Auth::user()->posts);
```

App/User

```
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Entities\posts', 'post_users', 'user_id', 'post_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

make relationship with post model on the user model:

```
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }
```

make relationship with user model on the post model:

```
 public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

in controller or Wherever you use:

```
  $userPosts = User::find($user->id)->posts->where('status', 1);
```